# Fix color transition from block title to body

Tags: beamer, color, block, transition

I'm trying to set up a block with my own colors, but the transition from the block title to the body just looks horrible.
[image: That's the block up to now]

I already had a look at [remove Beamer block transition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117811/remove-beamer-block-transition-between-title-and-body), the code obviously works, the colors still look different even if I put my color in the code for the transition bar. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123958/how-to-disable-color-gradient-between-block-title-and-block-body-in-beamer/123987#123987) doesn't do anything if included in my code either...

Any idea how to fix the transition (favourite) or get rid of it at all?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%Define colors
\definecolor{color1}{cmyk}{0.75 0 0.4 0}
\definecolor{color2}{cmyk}{0.75 0 0.4 0.1}
\definecolor{color3}{cmyk}{0.75 0 0.4 0.75}


%Change block colors
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=color2, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=color1, fg=color3}

%Change block design
\useinnertheme[shadow]{rounded}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{Some title}
$E=mc^2$
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I'm using the Torino theme but the outcome looks just the same.

Cheers

Markus

Comment: Try to convert your colors in `rgb` model:  `\definecolor{color1}{rgb:cmyk}{0.75 0 0.4 0}`

Comment: Thanks, now I know it's because my colors are defined in cymk. I tried your code, the transition is now smooth but the colors look absolutely different. So the transition uses rgb colors. Is there any way to make it work in cmyk, my colors are only defined in cmyk.

Comment: The `xcolor` package and your PDF viewer convert cmyk colors to rgb colors via different methods...

Comment: So how do I get the transition to use cmyk or make the transition disappear at all in the rounded style?

Comment: `beamer` uses rgb colors. Conversion between cmyk and rgb is device dependent and beamer uses perfect devices. You can pick the rgb color displays by your PDF viewer for each of your cmyk colors to get the same conversion as your PDF viewer.

Comment: Here, I get :
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{64,190,170}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{58,173,155}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{22,62,58}

Comment: Perfekt, those are pretty damn close! Thanks a lot. One last thing, how did you convert them, the online converters don't really look great.

Comment: You can pick RGB colors from your PNG picture above... via, for example, Gimp and its color picker tool.

Comment: Perfect, got all the colors converted in `rgb` with gimp, the transition is working. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You provide colors in `cmyk` model. To make shadings, `beamer` uses colors in `rgb` model.

### 1st solution

Convert your color in `rgb` model:

```
\definecolor{color1}{rgb:cmyk}{0.75 0 0.5 0}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb:cmyk}{0.75 0 0.4 0.3}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb:cmyk}{0.75 0 0.4 0.6}
```

You get:

[image]

### 2nd solution

The `xcolor` package converts color from `cmyk` model to `rgb` model for perfect hypothetic devices. PDF viewers uses devices dependent conversion with default sRGB profile. So, converted colors are not the same.

You may pick the color from a screen snapshot of your PDF viewer via a graphic editor (like `gimp`) and its color picker tool.

Here, I get:

```
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{64,190,170}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{58,173,155}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{22,62,58}
```

Result:

[image]