# The color of a shaded rectangle cannot be recovered in some cases

Tags: color, tcolorbox, shading

In the following MCE, a `tcolorbox` is equipped with two rectangles drawn as overlays. The color of these rectangles is supposed to be the same as the bottom color of the `tcolorbox`.

It works well with the color e.g. blue but not with cyan: why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\NewTColorBox{mybox}{ !O{blue} }
{
  enhanced,
  height=.75in,
  size=minimal,
  interior style={
    top color=black,
    bottom color=#1
  },
  overlay={
    \fill[#1]
    (frame.south west) rectangle +( .5in,-5)
    (frame.south east) rectangle +(-.5in,-5);
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
\end{mybox}

\vspace*{5cm}

\begin{mybox}[cyan]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}` before loading the `tcolorbox` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently the color `cyan` is defined as CMYK color. However, to generate the gradient, the color is converted into RGB mode (see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/454195/47927) about gradients and CMYK mode). The conversion to RGB mode results in visible differences for some colors, which is especially the case for cyan.

You can solve this problem by telling the `xcolor` package explicitly to only use RGB mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\NewTColorBox{mybox}{ !O{blue} }
{
  enhanced,
  height=.75in,
  size=minimal,
  interior style={
    top color=black,
    bottom color=#1
  },
  overlay={
    \fill[#1]
    (frame.south west) rectangle +( .5in,-5)
    (frame.south east) rectangle +(-.5in,-5);
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
\end{mybox}

\vspace*{5cm}

\begin{mybox}[cyan]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]